# Using Vagrant, is there a way to share/sync folder across multiple VMs?

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I want to have multiple VMs running on my system and for them each to have one or two folders synced with the host. I'm using vagrant coupled with virtualbox. When there is already a VM up (via vagrant up) Then a new VM is created (via vagrant up in another directory containing a different Vagrantfile) it doesn't get the shared/synced folder mounted. Is it possible to share/sync folders across multiple VMs and if so how?

Note: I have also tried using multi-machine i.e. editing the Vagrantfile to spin up multiple machines, but only one machine gets the shared folder.

---

#### Edit 4/22/15:

From discussion below, I believe this problem may result from using Virtualbox specifically. Will update after trying to repro on another OS and using another VM application.

Answer (score 2):

As described in [official documentation](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/basic_usage.html) you can setup specific synced folders in Vagrantfile. So you can setup the same shared folder for every project by simply putting something like this into every Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.synced_folder "../host_shared_src_folder", "/guest_src_folder"
```

So I have Vagrantfile like this

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "base_ubuntu"
  config.vm.synced_folder "../shared", "/shared"
end
```

And folder's layout

```
testvagrant
| -- shared
| -- testenv1
     | -- Vagrantfile
| -- testenv2
     | -- Vagrantfile
```

Then I just do *vagrant up* in both testenv1 and testenv2 folders and can see (and write to) shared folder under /shared

Comment: As stated before, this doesn't seem to work. Only the first VM actually get's the synced folders.

Comment: @M.J.Davis Please see an extra example above. Does this configuration work for you?

Comment: This does not work for me. The other VM boots and says it is mounting shared files and running provisioner, but once completed, the testenv2 does not have the shared folder mounted nor provisioned files. In fact, when I try to vagrant ssh into testenv2, it actually ssh's into testenv1. I do not understand why this happens. I tried even defining them differently and using "vagrant ssh testenv2", but no matter what the ssh goes into the first VM.

Comment: @M.J.Davis Sorry, I don't know how familiar you're with vagrant, but maybe you should try to perform ssh under the corresponding folder? To login to testenv1 do vagrant ssh under testvagrant/testenv1 and for testenv2 from under testvagrant/testenv2

Comment: It is curious that this doesn't work for me. I am following both the documentation and your comments exactly but the folders do not get mounted to the testenv2 and even in the testenv2 directory I get ssh'ed into testenv1 - even if I define them differently in the Vagrantfile and "vagrant ssh testenv2" from the testenv2 folder. Running OSX Yosemite and most current versions of vagrant and virtualbox.

Comment: Why you keep saying that you 'define them differently'. You got two different Vagrantfiles, right? In two different folders, right? And then you just need to change to that directory and issue 'vagrant ssh' (see, without testenv2). http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/ssh.html -- there is no way you specify witch VM you want to log into.

Comment: Actually you can with config.vm.define https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/multi-machine/index.html but I am doing it the way you specified with two difference Vagrantfiles and two different directories and it doesn't work for me. Not saying you're wrong, it might just be some kind of compatibility issue? I will try and repro this on another machine asap.

Comment: Okay, that smth I didn't know. But still this is odd. It should work since it's from docs. I'm using OSX and fusion though.

Comment: Since vagrant piggybacks on the folder sharing that virtualboxes provides, I think that may be it. I'll look into using fusion and maybe I'll have better luck. Thank you for the details.